# What to do if OS has killed an IntentService?

Tags: android, intentservice

Let's say we have an implementation of `IntentService`, then we start it from `Activity` and then add several other `Intent`s in a queue to `IntentService` for processing. So now we have first `Intent` under processing and the rest of `Intent`s in a queue. Now let's imagine  the OS kills our `Application` process because of understandable reason. The questions are:

1. How to restart the `IntentService`?
2. How to restore the queue?

Well, I know there is always a `Service` where you can override it's `onStartCommand()` and tell a `Service` what to do. But I need an `IntentService` because of its `queue` model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IntentService` is not what you want to use if the queue of work needs to be persistent. If you send many `Intent`s to an `IntentService` and then the process is killed by Android, there is no way to rebuild the queue. `IntentService` simply queues the `Intent`s up using an internal `Handler` and these are not persisted anywhere. They just get lost.

If I were you I would just implement this myself. The code for `IntentService` isn't that large and you can look at it and use it as a model for your own `Service`. You'll want to write your queue to a database so that it is persistent. Return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()` so that Android will automatically restart your `Service` if it is killed due to resource requirements.

Comment: Thanks, David. What about the first question? How to restart an `IntentService` if it was killed?

Comment: To restart it you would have to know that it has been killed. As I said in my answer, `IntentService` is not the right technique here. However, since you seem to want to use it in anyway, you can call `setIntentRedelivery(true)` in the constructor of your derived class. This will cause Android to automatically restart the `IntentService` if it is killed while processing an `Intent` (ie: if Android killed the process while it was doing work).

Comment: No,  I'll use the approach you suggested, just wanted to know about possible way for IntentService restart.  Thanks